# How do I instantiate schema objects?

Tags: c++, xml, soap, schema, gsoap

I have a schema structure, for example

```
class sw_Type
{
 char *Id;  /* required attribute */
 struct soap *soap; /* transient */
};
```

I create this object using

```
soap_instantiate__sw_Type(....)
```

but I can not understand how do I allocate the `char` entry. I suppose I should find a routine that accepts `soap` that returns `char *`. Should I be using `Id = (char *) (soap_malloc(_soapInst, sz * sizeof(char) ))`

how would I do similar allocation if `Id` was `char **`?

Comment: There is nothing magical about setting `char*` to point to strings. `Id` is just a string. To set it to another string `str` use `Id = soap_malloc(_soapInst, strlen(str) + 1)` and then `strcpy(Id, str)`. Or better, use `Id = soap_strdup(_soapInst, str)` as discussed in the docs http://www.genivia.com/doc/databinding/html/#memory. Not sure if that is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You should simply do as below and use a define for the length of the char array.

```
char * Id = (char *)soap_malloc(soap, ID_LEN);
```

No need to use `sizeof` in your example. But if you want to allocate a list of objects then you should use `Nof items x sizeof(struct ..)`.

Regarding `char**`, you can use something like the example below

```
char** arguments_push = (char**) soap_malloc(soap, sizeof(char*)*ARGS_NUM);
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on [thahgr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39706404/5689220), if you need to instantiate a `char**` member, you would do so just as they said:

```
Id = (char**) soap_malloc(soap, sizeof(char*) * n);
```

And then to instantiate each individual `char*` within that `char**`, you'd use `soap_malloc()` just as before:

```
Id[0] = (char*) soap_malloc(soap, n0);
Id[1] = (char*) soap_malloc(soap, n1);
// etc.
```

When you're finished with this `soap` context, all of this memory you allocated using `soap_malloc()` will be freed when you call `soap_free(soap)`.

(Likewise, any C++ objects you allocate using `soap_instantiate__T()`, e.g. `soap_instantiate__sw_Type()`, will be freed when you call `soap_destroy(soap)`)

---

**Note**: If you're using `char**` and you want `sw_Type` to be serialize-able (i.e. able to be output as a string), as is likely, you need to also add a `__size` member, just below the `Id` member:

```
class sw_Type
{
    char **Id;          /* required attribute */
    int __size;         /* required attribute */
    struct soap *soap;  /* transient */
};
```

See the gSOAP docs on [One-dimensional dynamic SOAP-encoded arrays](https://www.genivia.com/doc/guide/html/index.html#oned) for more info on `__size`.